# Curly brackets with no expression, conditional, or loop?

Tags: php, brackets

Here is something that I haven't seen before and my initial google-fu is failing me. What are these curly brackets doing in this below snippet?

```
function foo($x){
    {
        if(!isset($x)) $x = 0;
        $x++;
    }

    $html = "Foo has $x bar."
    return $html;
}
```

The above is just an example and please forgive if testing for $x is not something that would usually occur in these... standalone brackets.

Comment: Thanks, it look then like the answer (to my question) is "nothing" and they are just an alternative to comments.

Wish I could mark your comment as the solution!

Comment: Well, the solution wasn't my comment but the original answer (in the linked question) ;)

Comment: To be fair, I had no way of asking about "structuring code with curly braces" and my searches were along the lines of "curly braces no expression". 

I never would have turned up that thread. If not for you pointing it out it would have eluded me. So thank *you*!

Comment: I wondered if it would create a block out of which you could break, but it does not. For that you'd have to do `do{...}while(false);`